# KVM-QEMU Migration Code

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, migration

My lab setup is: 3 HP Servers each of 4 GB RAM. Server 1 and Server 2: installed with Virtualization using KVM on Redhat 6.5 System. On top of this I am using libvirtd for managing virtual machines. NFS server is installed on Server 3 for shared disk image. VM migration is working correctly. Now i need to do some changes in "migration.c" but did not find any source code of KVM-QEMU migration.
Where I can find the migration source code for KVM-QEMU. All are requested to help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

kvm is a kernel module in linux. now you should download and compile qemu source code. follow this link to do that :
https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux
.when you install libvirt, it will install qemu too, but for changing migration code you need to build qemu yourself.
migration code is available in qemu source code too.
good luck